# Google App Engine Instance - Strange behavior PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, instance, google-app-engine-php

I have some strange behavior in Google App Engine (PHP). I have deployed first version of my application in App Engine. I click on the Service, no response. The network shows `"(failed)"`. Ok so my guess is that there is no instance running.

I deployed again, then the old version works but not the new? Something is strange here.

[image]

As you can see the instance shows 0 on live version and other old versions are working and shows 1 instance. Why is that?

Comment: It is serving on HTTP but not HTTPS?

Comment: Could you specify where are you are seeing the error message, and at which moment? I reproduced the scenario, but did not encounter any network error.

Comment: Looks like it's working now? Strange, did not do anything but next day everything is ok. I did not get any error message that's why i did not understand anything. (failed) tells me nothing in network status. Looks like it just needed some time, maeby to install vendor files?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'vendor files'?

Answer (score 1):

The amount of GAE instances shown on your screenshot is not a real-time value, but just an estimate of [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://app.google.stackdriver.com/) (Hover over the question mark next to 'Instances'). If you wish to you view the actual values for the number of instances over time, use [Stackdriver Metrics Explorer](https://app.google.stackdriver.com/metrics-explorer).

Also, previous GAE versions don't shut down the instances immediately after deploying a new version, but after some amount of time has passed. Therefore it may still show the version as having an instance running.

Take into account that while the GAE version is serving, even despite of having 0% of the traffic, any access or traffic sent to this version, will start up a new instance.